# WordPress page navigation not working on tag.php

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

I'm trying to add pagination to my tag.php file in WordPress, to get it working I used `wp_pagenavi()`. I have set the `$paged` variable but for some reason when I click on page 2 it takes me to a broken page, attempted code:

```
 global $query_string;
 $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
 query_posts('posts_per_page=6&tag='.$current_tag."&paged=".$paged  ); 
 while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
 /* LOOP STUFF */

 endwhile;  
 wp_pagenavi(); 
 wp_reset_query(); 


 endif;
```

How can I get tag.php to go to page 2?

Comment: You shouldn't use `query_posts`, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/16288794/1981996

Comment: I think I need to use it for wp page navi though?

Comment: From the plugin's FAQ: http://scribu.net/wordpress/wp-pagenavi/right-way-to-use-query_posts.html

Comment: thanks it seems to be an issue with tag.php, ive modified the code above to declare the `$paged` variable properly but it is taking me to a broken page when I click the second page

Comment: Im unsure how to implement the request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in the comments above, remove the `query_posts` stuff from `tag.php` and modify the query from `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts','so16299109_pre_get_posts' );
function so16299109_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    if( is_tag() && $query->is_main_query() ){
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 6 );
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: thanks, I didnt realise that modification would be as simple as how you put it there. That worked.

Comment: may I ask just one other other thing, where is that number before pre get posts coming from? so16299109

Comment: That's the ID of the question here at Stackoverflow! Prefixing function names is considered good practice, see e.g. http://nacin.com/2010/05/11/in-wordpress-prefix-everything/